# What's the use of #ifdef and #endif processor directives in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, preprocessor, using-directives

I want to know about the use of #ifdef, #ifndef and #endif and which case, have to used those conditionals and what's the use of it? Whats the difference between the #ifdef and #ifndef?

For eg:

```
#define MY_Global

#ifdef MY_Global
  // write some code (Inside the method)
#endif
```

or,

```
  #ifdef MY_Global   
  -(void) customMethod
  {
       // Do something
  }
  #endif
```

Which one is correct, whether it should write only inside method or it does works outside method?. I haven't used this one before. so please Explain me?

Thanks!

Comment: The second one means `customMethod` will be totally missing if `MY_Global` is not defined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, #ifdef = "if defined" and #ifndef = "if not defined". These conditionals are useful, for example if you want a certain code to be compiled only for the simulator, then you'd write something like:

```
    #if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
    #import "AccelerometerSimulation.h"
    #endif
```

Which means, when you compile for the simulator, the AccelerometerSimulation.h will be imported. If you are compiling on a device, it is ignored totally. Hope that helps.

Comment: You can in fact write `#if defined(NAME)` and `#if !defined(NAME)` instead of `#ifdef NAME` and `#ifndef NAME`. This also lets you test for the definition of multiple names in one go: `#if defined(NAME1) && defined(NAME2)`.